# Sharepoint list xsl:merging javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, xslt

Banging my head against the wall.....
I have a SP list that uses an ajax script to pull different content into a page on click. I want the site owner to be able to enter a value in the list to determine which content is called up when the page opens.
The  xsl:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Data/Row">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript:ajaxpage('<xsl:value-ofselect="./@Target_x0020_page"/>','<xsl:value-of select="./@Target_x0020_div"/>');</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@Category"/>
    </a>
</xsl:for-each>
```

JS to open default content:

```
ajaxpage('2minxcat2.aspx' , 'index')
```

I've tried an `xsl:if` but it gets ignored.
Any help appreciated.

Clarification;
@CBono Sorry-the js is called with a link and works fine. This is an Office Live Small Business site-the xml is auto generated off the list and the xsl called in with a link. I'm trying to include this additional js snippet in the xsl so the owner can change which ajax content gets called in when the page opens by simply making a change in the list:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> ajaxpage('contenturlhere' , 'targetdiv') </script>
```

I've tried adding this:

```
 <xsl:if test="Opening_x0020_category = 1"><script type="text/javascript">ajaxpage('<xsl:value-of select="./@Target_x0020_page"/>
```

','')

But nothing gets outputted. It works as expected when the javascript above is inserted outside of the xsl. 
The logic I want is "If one of the list items has a '1' in a specified field, insert this  content in this div when the page opens".

XML:
[Link](http://essentials-hairandbeauty.co.uk/Documents/wb_minxnailsindex.txt)

Comment: You haven't explained the problem very well. Where is the Javascript running? Where is the XSL running and how is it called?

Comment: whats the problem in your code kindly explain

Comment: @CBono Sorry-the js is called with a link and works fine. This is an Office Live Small Business site-the xml is auto generated off the list and the xsl called in with a link. I'm trying to include this additional js snippet in the xsl so the owner can change which ajax content gets called in when the page opens by simply making a change in the list:<script type="text/javascript">
ajaxpage('contenturlhere' , 'targetdiv') 
</script>

Comment: You should read how to format your code ;-)

Comment: Heh-I pasted over the "enter code here", I indented 4 spaces-it still looks like cr*p.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you just needed specify that you're testing an **attribute** of the current node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rebuilt it line by line and it worked. The problem was the js not the xsl. Somehow the js was getting broken up *after* I entered it. When I made sure it was on one line, it worked.
My own dumb fault. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the single quotes inside your call to `ajaxpage`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">ajaxpage(&apos;<xsl:value-of select="./@Target_x0020_page"/>&apos;, &apos;<xsl:value-of select="./@Target_x0020_div"/>&apos;);</script>
```

---

**Update:** Looking at the XML source, it appears your `xsl:if` statement is testing an attribute of the current node. I think it should read:

```
<xsl:if test="@Opening_x0020_category = 1">
     <!-- your_output -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that both within the xsl for each and outside and it still just ignores the if statement. Here's a rough page - the idea being one of the content pages would open in the middle column when the page opens.  [link](http://essentials-hairandbeauty.co.uk/2test4.aspx)

Comment: So when you don't use the `xsl:if` statement, everything works?

Comment: The rest of the code works with or without the if statement. If I add it, it doesn't output anything. I would expect it to loop through the list items and run the js if it finds an item with a '1' in the specified field and do nothing if it doesn't. Does that make sense? Or am I "iffing" on the wrong thing?

Comment: I'm just trying to narrow down the exact source of the problem. I think, then, it could be your `if` syntax. Can you post a sample of your XML?

Comment: thank you for looking at this. I posted it in the orig question-I hope you can see it (it looked weird after posting in the "enter code" box).

Comment: That was actually a typo-I've tried it with @Opening_x0020_category and ./@ and still no output. Am I correct in assuming this should look at the list and only output the list item with a '1' in the specified field or is my logic faulty? My concern is the other list items will have a zero instead of 1 so is it seeing the zeros and returning false?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your **entire** XSL. I was assuming that the `xsl:if` statement occurred inside the `xsl:for-each` that loops through the \Data\Row nodes. If this is not the case, your code block will never execute... you'd need to do something like set up a template to output your script block, and call the template using `xsl:call-template`.